# Rewrite rule is not working when I'm getting the value of GET in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 

#FIRST RULE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#2ND RULE    
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L]

#3RD RULE
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./edit-page?edit=$1
```

Now let me explain the code above.

FIRST rewrite rule will remove all `.php` extension, so if I have `http://localhost:8888/index.php` I can access it with `http://localhost:8888/index` without .php extension

SECOND rewrite rule will convert this link:

```
http://localhost:8888/CodeArk/?page=introduction-page
```

into

```
http://localhost:8888/CodeArk/introduction-page
```

The problem is the last rule (3rd RULE).

it suppose to convert this link:

```
http://localhost:8888/CodeArk/edit-page/?edit=introduction-page
```

into

```
http://localhost:8888/CodeArk/edit-page/introduction-page
```

Now this doesnt works because when I tried to get the value of `edit` in edit-page.php file

edit-page.php

```
echo "YOUR EDIT IS: "$_GET['edit'];
```

the output is

```
YOUR EDIT IS: edit-page/introduction-page.php/introduction-page
```

What happened? the output should be only this

```
YOUR EDIT IS: introduction-page
```

I suspect that my rewrite rules is the cause, but I dont know the cause. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L]
```